# Use Zenject FromSubContainerResolve on ProjectContext to SceneContext

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, zenject

I have a Unity + Zenject setup with a `ProjectInstaller` with some global dependencies that adhere to a "modal" interface, e.g.,

```cs
public class ProjectInstaller : MonoInstaller {
  public override void InstallBindings() {
    Container.Bind<ModalManager>().AsSingle();

    Container.Bind<Modal>().To<DialogManager>().AsSingle();
  }
}
```

Some modals are only relevant to certain scenes, so I bind those in the `SceneInstaller`:

```cs
public class SceneInstaller : MonoInstaller {
  public override void InstallBindings() {
    Container.BindInterfacesAndSelfTo<InventoryManager>()
      .FromComponentInNewPrefab(InventoryPrefab)
      .AsSingle()
  }
}
```

I want to manage **all** modals from the single `ModalManager`, defined at the project scope. So it has a `List<Modal>` binding:

```cs
public class ModalManager : MonoBehaviour {
    [Inject]
    protected List<Modal> _modals;
}
```

When I run this, the `ModalManager` only gets a single modal: the one defined in the project scope.  In my understanding the `SceneContext` is a subcontainer of the `ProjectContext`. So I should be able to use `FromSubContainerResolve` in the `ProjectInstaller` to bind items in the child scene, perhaps by adding a line like:

```cs
// ProjectInstaller.cs
public override void InstallBindings() {
  // ...
  Container.Bind<Modal>().To<InventoryManager>().FromSubContainerResolve();
}
```

But I'm not sure which of the eleventy `FromSubContainerResolve` methods make sense for this case. They all seem pertinent to prefabs with a game object context, *not* for use from within the `ProjectContext`.

Does this use case make sense? Is there an easier or better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that that `ModalManager` can only be injected with dependencies that are added directly to ProjectContext.   For these kinds of problems I recommend using the following pattern:

```
public interface IModal
{
}

public class ModalManager
{
    private readonly List<IModal> _modals = new List<IModal>();

    public IReadOnlyList<IModal> Modals
    {
        get { return _modals; }
    }

    public void AddModal(IModal modal)
    {
        _modals.Add(modal);
    }

    public bool RemoveModal(IModal modal)
    {
        return _modals.Remove(modal);
    }
}

public class ModalRegisterHandler : IInitializable, IDisposable
{
    private readonly List<IModal> _modals;
    private readonly ModalManager _modalManager;

    public ModalRegisterHandler(
        // We need to use InjectSources.Local here, otherwise we will
        // add any project context modals again in each scene
        [Inject(Source = InjectSources.Local)]
        List<IModal> modals, ModalManager modalManager)
    {
        _modals = modals;
        _modalManager = modalManager;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        foreach (var modal in _modals)
        {
            _modalManager.AddModal(modal);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // We don't want ModalManager to retain references to Modals defined in unloaded scenes
        // (dispose is executed on scene unload)
        foreach (var modal in _modals)
        {
            _modalManager.RemoveModal(modal);
        }
    }
}

public class SceneInstaller : MonoInstaller
{
    public override void InstallBindings()
    {
        Container.Bind<IModal>().To<FooModal>();
        Container.Bind<IModal>().To<BarModal>();
    }
}

public class ProjectInstaller : MonoInstaller
{
    public override void InstallBindings()
    {
        // We use CopyIntoDirectSubContainers so that ModalRegisterHandler gets automatically added to every 
        // scene context
        Container.BindInterfacesTo<ModalRegisterHandler>().AsSingle().CopyIntoDirectSubContainers();

        Container.Bind<ModalManager>().AsSingle();

        Container.Bind<IModal>().To<QuxModal>();
        Container.Bind<IModal>().To<FizzModal>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, that's a clever workaround. Appreciate the quick response Steve!

Comment: `// We use CopyIntoDirectSubContainers so that ModalRegisterHandler gets automatically added to every // scene context` -> I found this confusing because I thought that bindings were visible by the container itself and its children so this should not be needed. Aren't the bindings inherited directly in subcontainers?

Comment: @rustyBucketBay the binding is inherited, but since he's using `BindInterfacesTo` my hunch is he's adding its `IInitializable` / `IDisposable` lifecycle into each child scene context. So those `Initialize` and `Dispose` methods will be invoked on each scene transition automatically!